# Vb.net AddHandler MouseHover

Tags: vb.net, winforms, addhandler

My Code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim top As Integer = 0
        For i = 0 To 10
            Dim inLine As Integer = 8
            Dim left As Integer = 0
            For x = 0 To inLine
                Dim s As New Panel
                s.BackColor = Color.Black
                s.Width = 10
                s.Height = 10
                s.Left = left
                s.Top = top
                left = left + 20
                AddHandler s.MouseHover, AddressOf Panel1_MouseHover
                Me.Controls.Add(s)
            Next
            top = top + 20
        Next

    End Sub

        Private Sub Panel1_MouseHover(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
   /////---- Some code!! :/ 
        End Sub
```

My code adding panels into my from ,
 i want that when Mouse Hover on panel
the panel change the background color.

if someone not understand:
when my mouse hover my panel that i add to my form, how i change the panel back color?

```
Private Sub Panel1_MouseHover(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
       /////---- Some code to change the panel color !! :/ 
End Sub
```

Comment: What's your question?  (hint: it should be followed by a question mark)

Comment: [Control.BackColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.backcolor.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the part you're missing is the fact that the `sender` parameter to the event handler method will always be whichever control it is that is raising the event.  Before using it though, I would cast it to the correct type so you get the full advantages of intellisense and compiler type checking.

```
Private Sub Panel1_MouseHover(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim panel As Panel = CType(sender, Panel)
    panel.BackColor = Color.White
End Sub
```